# Tkinter generates excess space in grid, how to use grid more efficiently?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Tkinter generates excess space in grid:

[image]

'Button 1' and 'Entry 1' shares 'row 0' and 'column 0'.
Size and Position work dynamically in this "cell".

Same for 'Button 2' and 'Button 3'.

Problem:

1. 'Entry 1' doesn't fill the space of the cell.
2. The empty Space on r/c 0 would be added to r/c 1 (see pic).

How to fix this, to use the grid more efficiently?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry()
root.title('Test-Window')

button1 = Button(root, text='Button 1')
button1.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=0)

button1.update()
entry1_padx = button1.winfo_width() + 1

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(padx=entry1_padx, row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(root, text='Button 2')
button2.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=1)

button2.update()
button3_padx = button2.winfo_width() + 1

button3 = Button(root, text='Button 3')
button3.grid(padx=button3_padx, sticky='W', row=0, column=1)

label1 = Label(root, text='this is were the cell ends')
label1.grid(sticky="E", row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you add buttons and entries in the same cells? You could make 4 columns and leave `padx`. Also, you can use `columnspan=2` for `label1` if you want to span it over multiple columns.

Comment: Note that `padx=value` will apply `value` paddings on both sides, use `padx=(value,0)` instead to apply on left side only.

Answer (score 0):

1, 2: Because 'padx' adds padding on the left and right.

Widget placement is easy with tk.Frame.

The import only needs to be done once.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry()
root.title('Test-Window')

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)

frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text='Button 1')
button1.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=0)

entry1 = tk.Entry(frame1)
entry1.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=1)

button2 = tk.Button(frame2, text='Button 2')
button2.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=0)

button3 = tk.Button(frame2, text='Button 3')
button3.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=1)

label1 = tk.Label(frame3, text='this is were the cell ends')
label1.grid(sticky="E", row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps in resolving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing with excess space in the grid can be resolved by adjusting the column weights and configuring the Entry widget to fill the available space.

Try this code.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test-Window')

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1')
button1.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=0)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(sticky='WE', row=0, column=1)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2')
button2.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=2)

button3 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 3')
button3.grid(sticky='W', row=0, column=3)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='This is where the cell ends')
label1.grid(sticky='E', row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

# Configure column weights to distribute excess space evenly
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

In this code, the changes made include:

- Configured the Entry widget ( `entry1` ) to stick to both west and east ( `sticky='WE'` ), allowing it to fill the available space horizontally.
- Utilized `columnspan=4` for `label1` to span across all four columns.
- Added `root.grid_columnconfigure()` calls to assign weights to each column, which will distribute the excess space evenly among them.

Comment: This looks like it was generated by an AI, not by a human. ChatGPT is banned on Stack Overflow. Please delete this before you get in more trouble: we take plagiarism seriously here.

Comment: This answer has a high probability of being AI content. Please read Stack Overflow's guide on AI content: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy